# Crossbow of Extra Shots (+1) Only Uses One Bolt

Tags: angband

So, I just found a Heavy Crossbow of Extra Shots [...] (+1). When I fire it, I notice that it only uses one bolt; judging by the status messages, it seems like enemies are only being hit once.

What's up with that?

When I press shift-C, the character screen assures me that I get "Shots: 2/turn."

I'm playing as a Half-Troll Warrior; I heard that bows of extra shots are the only way to get more than one shot off at a time, but I don't seem to be getting that.

I'm not sure if it's important, but my strength is 18/160 and my dexterity is 15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an [explanation](http://angband.oook.cz/forum/showthread.php?t=282) to how it works:

> In Angband, your character has an "energy" stat, which is not shown. Each game turn you gain an amount of energy which is determined by your speed (10 energy at speed +0). Whenever you reach 100 energy you get to take a turn (so one "player turn" equals 10 "game turns" at normal speed).
>
> Almost all actions (moving, melee attacking, disarming,
>   spiking/bashing a door, using a scroll/potion/device, putting on a
>   piece of kit etc.) take exactly 100 energy. In some variants some
>   actions take less time (dropping stuff, dousing your lamp), but these
>   are minor.
>
> The one big exception to the 100 energy rule is extra missile shots
>   (whether granted by equipment or the ranger bonus shots). The game
>   works out your total number of shots per turn and divides this into
>   100. So if you have 2 shots, each takes 50 energy. If you have 3, each takes 33 energy. Etc. It's a bit of a kludge really, but it seems to
>   work.

Does that seem to be happening?

Comment: I'm not observant enough to tell if it's working or not. But when I filed a bug on Trac for Angband, this is essentially the same response that I got :)